# Equivalent of app.executor.to_run and .to_complete in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

I'm looking to make the following code work on Rails 4.2:

```
initializer "action_policy.clear_per_thread_cache" do |app|
    app.executor.to_run { ActionPolicy::PerThreadCache.clear_all }
    app.executor.to_complete { ActionPolicy::PerThreadCache.clear_all }
end
```

I'm aware the executor is a Rails 5 feature but couldn't find out much about how this was achieved in Rails 4.2 and below. There is a guide but I didn't see much in there: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/threading_and_code_execution.html

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is to use a Middleware:

```
initializer "action_policy.clear_per_thread_cache" do |app|
  if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 5
    app.executor.to_run { ActionPolicy::PerThreadCache.clear_all }
    app.executor.to_complete { ActionPolicy::PerThreadCache.clear_all }
  else
    app.middleware.use ActionPolicy::Middleware
  end
end
```

Here's the middleware:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ActionPolicy # :nodoc:
  class Middleware # :nodoc:
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      ActionPolicy::PerThreadCache.clear_all
      status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
      ActionPolicy::PerThreadCache.clear_all

      [status, headers, response]
    end
  end
end
```